# Two players and three spinners game probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Im working on a question that reads "Two players play the following game: player A chooses one of three spinners then B chooses one of the remaining two. The three spinners read (9,5,1),(3,8,4),(7,6,2). Assuming each spinner is equally likely to land on one of the three numbers, would you rather be player A or B."

I tried to start this but am finding it very confusing. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Assume you're player $A$; you pick a spinner. What is the probability that $B$ beats you? If we play Rock Paper Scissors, you would rather be player B (he always wins). If we play Rock Paper, you would rather be player A (she always wins).

Comment: is the prob b beats a 2/3?

Comment: i havent been able to make it that far. i have a solution (not my own) but do not understand it

Comment: A has to pick a spinner. If he can, B picks one that beats A's. For instance, if A chooses (9,5,1), then B will choose (7,6,2). There are 9 outcomes: (9,7), (9,6), (9,2), (5,7), (5,6), (5,2), (1,7), (1,6), (1,2). B wins in 5 of those, so his probability of winning is 5/9 (not 2/3 as I agreed to above, sorry). You need to do the same analysis if A chooses each of the other two spinners.

Comment: This is a problem in the book by an excellent math professor on West coast ( southern Cal I think ) Sheldon Ross " first course in probability " .. one of best books I've met and quickly added to collection 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ chooses spinner (7,6,2), then if $B$ chooses (9,5,1), there are $9$ possible outcomes: (7,9), [7,5], [7,1], (6,9), [6,5], [6,1], (2,9), (2,5), [2,1]. The ones in square brackets are wins for $A$, so $A$ wins with probability $5/9$. **(7,6,2) beats (9,5,1).**

If $A$ chooses spinner (7,6,2), and $B$ chooses spinner (8,4,3), then there are $9$ possible outcomes again: (7,8), [7,4], [7,3], (6,8), [6,4], [6,3], (2,8), (2,4), (2,3). The ones in square brackets are wins for $A$, so $A$ wins with probability $4/9$. **(8,4,3) beats (7,6,2).** We don't have to do this 6 times, just one more.

If $A$ chooses spinner (9,5,1) and $B$ chooses (8,4,3), then $A$ wins with probability 5/9. So **(9,5,1) beats (8,4,3).**

To summarize, (9,5,1) beats (8,4,3), (8,4,3) beats (7,6,2), and (7,6,2) beats (9,5,1). This is a classic situation like rock/paper/scissors. You would rather be player B, and you will win with probability $5/9$ (because you will choose the spinner that beats whatever $A$ chose).

Comment: I get it now..I kept thinking under the assumption B doesnt know which one A picked but that makes no sense. thanks for the help!!